# emacsclient: connect: Connection refused

Tags: emacsclient, daemon

I am trying to run `emacs-daemon` on a remote machine (connected via `ssh`), which was working fine. After I try to setup ports for mosh between `60000:61000` emacs-daemon started not to open :-(

The way I start emacs: `emacsclient -t -q`

`echo $DISPLAY` returns empty. Please note that I am not using any X11 connection.

---

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 27.1

$ emacsclient --version
emacsclient 26.3
```

---

The error output I get:

```
emacsclient: connect: Connection refused

Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
Starting Emacs daemon.
Unable to start the daemon.
Another instance of Emacs is running the server, either as daemon or interactively.
You can use emacsclient to connect to that Emacs process.
Error: server did not start correctly
Error: Could not start the Emacs daemon
```

=> Could it be related to emacs version or ports? How could I debug and fix this issue?

Comment: I'd start upgrading emacsclient to the same version than emacs.

Comment: latest version is `emacsclient26`

Comment: `sudo apt remove --autoremove emacs26` and later `sudo apt install emacs26` fixed the issue